# How to get Saturday date from Calendar in java for a specified week?

Tags: java, date

I have a date which is date of a week day(Monday to friday). For example date which I have is 06-07-2016(wednesday). It can be any day from Monday to Friday. And I want to get the previous Saturday (02-07-2016)date of that date.How can I achieve this?

Comment: I really dont have an idea how to get this

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Seriously, a person with 2K reputation; and you expect such a question to fly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a good way to get the date of the coming Wednesday?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463756/is-there-a-good-way-to-get-the-date-of-the-coming-wednesday)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the last Sunday before current date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783102/how-to-get-the-last-sunday-before-current-date)

Comment: I wrote u a code which will help you. But this is duplicate for sure @seethalakshmi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using java 8 fluent Date/Time classes:

```
LocalDate inputDate = ...
LocalDate prevSat = inputDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.previous(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY));
```

Comment: the date which i am setting can be a past date as well not current date

Comment: here you go.... was it that hard??

Comment: @seethalakshmi, check the documantation for LocalDate to manipulate the date in the past, present or future. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: Thanks @ sharonbn ..it is working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, - cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)); 
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here. 2 working solutions. I'm first calculating how much days passed till last Saturday and then I'm making new date in which i deduct number which i get from method. That is giving us exact date of last saturday. Second solution is simpler, its using Java 8 features.

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CalendarSat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate()-lastSut(date.getDay()));
        System.out.println("Custom solution with method: " + date);

        LocalDate inputDate = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate prevSat = inputDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.previous(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY));
        System.out.println("Java 8 solution: " + prevSat);

    }

    public static int lastSut(int currentDay) {
        int toRet = 0;
        int num = 6;
        for(int i = 0; i<7;i++) {
            if(num==currentDay) {
                toRet=i;
            }
            if(currentDay==0)
                currentDay=7;
            currentDay--;       
        }       
        return toRet;
    }
}
```